# Understanding the Lazy fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

```
@Entity
public class Bid {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "bid_id")
    private Long bidId;

    @Column(name = "bid_amt")
    private double bidAmount;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private String person;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Item.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bid_item", referencedColumnName = "item_id", nullable = false)
    private Item item;

    public Long getBidId() {
        return bidId;
    }

    public double getBidAmount() {
        return bidAmount;
    }

    public String getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setBidAmount(final double bidAmount) {
        this.bidAmount = bidAmount;
    }

    public void setPerson(final String person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public void setItem(final Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Bid() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bid [bidId=" + bidId + ", bidAmount=" + bidAmount + ", person="
                + person + /* ", item=" + item + */"]";
    }

}
```

Test Case:

```
@Test
    public void testBidRead() {
        final Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        final List<Bid> bids = currentSession.createQuery("from Bid").list();
        for (final Bid bid : bids) {
            System.out.println(bid);
        }
    }
```

And the SQL the Hibernate generated is:

```
/* 
from
    Bid */ select
        bid0_.bid_id as bid1_1_,
        bid0_.bid_amt as bid2_1_,
        bid0_.bid_item as bid4_1_,
        bid0_.person as person1_ 
    from
        Bid bid0_
```

Question: Although I marked `person` attribute as *lazy && optional*, why is it part of SQL query? Does this mean that Hibernate is not fetching lazily? Same is the case with Item.

How do I fetch attributes lazily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the person attribute (as opposed to association) truly lazy, you must bytecode instrument your classes at build time. The reference documentation has some information on how to do it.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

Answer (score 2):

`Person` is a single (string) property

Fetching it while other fetching (for the non-lazy fetches like `bidId` and `bidAmount`) is done on the same object is common sense

As the query has to be executed anyway and transporting a `varchar` (or whatever) along with the `bidId` and `bidAmount` is not much overhead

And it loads in the item *id* (not the item itself) so that the item itself can be loaded when you call `getItem()` without another query to get the id (caching the id in between the construction and `getItem()` call)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that hibernate is loading just foreign key values, not the whole Person or Item. What's wrong with it?